# listing all contacts lists in joomla

Tags: joomla

How can I lists the contacts like below:

[image]

I created categories and contacts from components and assigned it in a menu but display like this:

```
branch1:
branch2:
branch3:
```

and other heading titles

How can I accomplish this proper way in joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has this feature, however it will require some work from you, if you wish to have it styled like you do in your question.

Firstly, you will need to create a new Menu Item and set the "**type**" to "**List Contact in a Category**". Select the category, save it, and when you go to the page, you will see the list.

To change the structure, **don't** go changing all of the core CSS file and PHP files. Instead, do a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

In your case, the file that will need to be changed is:

```
components/com_contact/views/category/tmpl/default.php
```

All you need to do is create the following directory structure if you dont have it already:

```
templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_contact/category
```

then copy the `default.php` from the first directory, to your newly create one and start editing to suit your needs

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way. Model just doesn't load items for nested categories and as of Joomla 3.5.1 there is no switch anywhere.

However There is a nasty workaround: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/is-there-a-way-to-display-category-items-in-categories-listing

Answer (score 0):

For `Category view` in file `default_children.php` after tag `<li...` add code:

```
    <?php

    // Get Category Model data
    $categoryModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Category', 'ContactModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

    $categoryModel->setState('category.id', $child->id);
    $categoryModel->setState('list.ordering', 'a.name');
    $categoryModel->setState('list.direction', 'asc');
    $categoryModel->setState('filter.published', 1);

    $contacts = $categoryModel->getItems();

    ?>
```

For `Custom Fields` add first line after previus code, and in cycle get custom field for each contact:

```
    JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
    foreach($contacts as $contactItem) {
        $currentContFields[] = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_contact.contact', $contactItem, true);
}
```